# Token-based authentication in Java EE 6

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-ee, jersey, glassfish-3

I want to implement a token-based authentication mechanism for a scenario which is similar to the following:

In Google Calendar, you can invite guests to your event, who in turn can respond to these events right from the email invitation. The invitation to such an event contains the respective links to respond (Yes, No, Maybe) with authentication tokens encoded in the URL. These authentication tokens are restricted to the specific event and user.

What's the best practice to generate these kinds of "one-time" tokens that can only perform limited actions and have only access to limited resources (and potentially are only valid for a limited amount of time)? And how do I implement this in Glassfish? I want to expose this through the RESTful API of my application (using Jersey). Currently, all URL paths in my app are secured with an authentication constraint, which I configured in the web.xml.

My approach to this would be as follows:

1. Provide a URL where no authentication constraint is applied (e.g. /token_auth) and use this for token authentication.
2. In the web service method, manually check the security tokens and do the required actions. The tokens are saved in the DB along with information such as username, expiration date, authorized resources, etc.

I was wondering whether there is a more elegant solution using any frameworks or built-in container capabilities that can avoid all the manual work. And whether this solution might have some security drawbacks.

A similar question has been asked on SO before: [Newbie at JAAS authentication; Sign in using a token in the URL Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252940/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into UUIDs?

At work we use the [Safehaus UUID](http://jug.safehaus.org/curr/javadoc/org/safehaus/uuid/UUID.html).

Comment: No, I looked at it. What's the advantage of it over Java's built-in UUID class. Efficiency? What about the rest of my question, would you approach the issue the same way I described? Do you also use Glassfish at work?

Comment: I personally don't know the reasoning behind using the Safehaus version of UUID over the default java implementation.  I can find out the differences if needed.

Comment: In general I would be wary of using tokens for authorization on anything that might allow access to personal information, like a calendar.  Have you considered generating a url that has the event information and then have the user's sent the url logging in instead of granting access just because of a token?  I have not used Glassfish or Jersey, but my guess is that really doesn't matter in this case.  What is the security framework you're using?  If you're not using one, you might consider using spring security 3.

Comment: In case you're interested: I've found a post that compares three UUID generators: http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/java/Java-UUID-generators-compared.html

Answer (score 1):

You approach looks fine. I am not aware of a framework to do this kind of thing for you. [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) may have something you can use but not the whole thing.