# Jersey-request for authentication

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication, glassfish, jersey

I have a working JavaEE 6 web application on Glassfish, this application already has a JSF frontend and has its authentication mechanism((Using CDI and annotation based security) So there is a login screen, user enters username password, press login button and Java EE authentication process begins.

Now I want to "also" expose some of my service classes as a REST service (I will use Jersey probably), so it can also be reached from a mobile device. But what worries me is the login part.

I will use the exact same existing authentication But now I want my application will get this credentials from a Rest Request but not from the login screen. And then continue using the existing validation methods which already exists(check username password from DB,,etc)

I kinda got lost how can I do this, I think I need to use one of these filters to intercept the request and get the username password but not sure how and which one? Or I dont need anything like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can protect the REST service the same way you protect the REST service, for example:

```
@Path("/foo")
@RolesAllowed({"admin", "customer"})
public class Foo {

@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
@RolesAllows("admin")
public void adminOnly() {}

public void adminOrCustomer() {}

}
```

I guess you already have roles and mappings for them so just use the same roles you got, the application server will take care of the rest.

Comment: tnx yes I use roles, but I am new to JEE so I would be happy if you explain a bit more, I dont need any listeners to intercept the request and stripe the username  password? Where can I get them?

Comment: If you want to validate credentials you usually implement some UserRegistry (I'm not too familiar with Glassfish) and the application server do that. Mostly after validation the server generates a token and sends it back to the client and the client uses that token from that time. You should read about Glashfish security, I was under the impression you already figured out how to do it for other servelets.

Comment: Segalso what does the code do? only authorize the resources for given roles?

Comment: there is an existing validation mechanism, I just want it to receive the username password from rest call not login screen

Comment: Basically you can get the `Resuest` object in the rest method and get anything form there but I would try my best to let the application server handle security and not implement anything myself unless I really have to