# How to authenticate users in Java(REST) app?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, authentication, web

I have some java server application and some WEB interface(jQuery). For REST services i'm using Jersey implementation. I can easily sent JSON to the server from WEB page and vice versa.

**Example of my REST service:**

```
@Path("/users")
public class User {

 @POST
 @Path("/login")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response authUser(User user) {
   //code
 }
}
```

But there is one problem. How can I auth users? 
For example, i have some private resources: when user in not log in, he can't see it resource/web page, but when he logined(enter correct name and password) he can see it resource.

I didn't use sping application. I have googled a lot of time but I didn't find easy examples, then i tried to read Jose's Sandoval book "RESTful Java Web Services", in "Security" section a lot of useful information but there isn't examples.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to approach this I believe. One way is that when the user authenticates, you send him back a token [which expires after some time] and he then passes back that token in subsequent calls.

Save the token to a file or db. In subsequent requests that come from client , compare token timestamp and value.

Once that token expires he has to re-authenticate.

Comment: Thank your for a response. I've read about it, in book it calls Custom token authentication", but don  know how to realize it? Maybe you have some simple example?

Comment: I have only googled for an example. I really didn't know how to solve this problem. So I  trying to find some simple example.

Comment: Of course, I've read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987165/java-rest-service-using-authentication-token

Comment: Hmm, thx for the idea. But there is one more question. When I will  send this token to the web client, this token will be stored in the HTTP header?

Comment: @JavaDude in the response of a successful authentication. Http Header sounds correct.